# AdWords auto-tagging with utm parameters instead of gclid

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

Is it possible to configure AdWords to auto-tag with `utm` parameters instead of/as well as the `gclid` parameter?

I'd like to be able to grab this data and do something with it, but the `gclid` doesn't seem to yield any useful data other than the timestamp (https://deedpolloffice.com/blog/articles/decoding-gclid-parameter).

Does anyone know if this is possible? If not, is there a way to get more data from the `gclid`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use glcid and autotagging in the same url, but you cannot make Adwords tag your urls with utm parameters. If you want additional information that is automatically filled in you can use [valueTrack-Parameters](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375447?hl=en) instead. Most relevant to you would probably be the {{campaignid}}, {{adgroup}} and {{keyword}} placeholders, Adwords will subsitute the proper values.

Comment: That looks promising, can I use ValueTrack to automatically add certain parameters to all ads? There are ~900 ads in this account which is why I was hoping `utm` params could be added automatically.

Comment: No, you need to append the placeholders manually. If you need the same parameters for all landing page urls you might consider to use adwords script to automate the link changes (that's basically a subsegment of javascript, if you know javascript at all it will be quicker to write a script than to change the landing page url manually).